# Expanding abp.io abp-lookup

Tags: abp, abp.io

Looking at the abp-lookup components, such as abp-lookup-typeahead in ABP.io using v7.3.3 and Angular

It doesn't seem possible to create a trigger on the return value to populate additional fields (ie select a customer, populate address), or to create a custom list of results - eg for a customer, you may have (CODE0001) - Customer Name.

Is there any way of achieving this to:

1. Return additional information on a lookup request to populate additional fields
2. Trigger a function by passing the selected id from the lookup to pull in additional information or to process additional information on the lookup output.
3. Formulating the display of matching results to include extra fields.

I am guessing this is not possible without writing our own components.